# Lie algebra version of principal bundle?

Tags: principal-bundles, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am wondering whether there is a Lie algebraic version of principal bundle for Lie group over a given manifold $M$. The first thing I try to think of is group cocycle picture of principal bundle.

Comment: Try Atyiah algebroid.

Answer (score 4):

A very comprehensive source is:

MR2157566 Mackenzie, Kirill C. H. General theory of Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids. London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 213. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2005. xxxviii+501 pp.

Starting from the total space,
there is also the notion of the action of a Lie algebra on a manifold, which one can extend to a Lie group action by enlarging the manifold (and loosing Hausdorff in general), see
[here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/lie-completion.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Peter's answer,  An Atiyah algebroid, or transitive Lie algebroid is one answer to your question.